# Vectors and Cross Product in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

[image]

I set the vector V as (a,b,c). I know that you have to multiply out the two vectors, so that is what I did. I then got multiple equations which I used to find the values of a, b, and c. The answer that I got was (2,2,-5), however, that solution only works for the equation on the bottom. I don't know how else to do this problem. Any ideas/answers?

Comment: [$(a,b,c)^T\times (1,0,-3)^T=(-3 b, 3 a + c, -b)^T$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vector+product+of+%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D+and+%7B1%2C0%2C-3%7D) and $(-3 b, 3 a + c, -b)=(-6,11,-2)$ with $(a,b,c)^T.(1,-5,1)=-7$ gives [$(a,b,c)=(4,2,-1)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B-3+b%2C+3+a+%2B+c%2C+-b%7D%3D%3D%7B-6%2C11%2C-2%7D+%26%26+%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D.%7B1%2C-5%2C1%7D%3D-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(a,b,c)\times(1,0,-3)=(-3b,3a+c,-b)$, you should solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-3b=-6\\3a+c=11\\-b=-2.\end{array}\right.$$You will get that $b=2$ and $c=11-3a$. And, in order to have $(a,2,11-3a).(1,-5,1)=-7$, $a$ shall have to be equal to $4$. So, the answer is $(4,2,-1)$.

Comment: Ohh, I understand now. It didn't even cross my mind to substitute c as 11 - 3a. That is what I was stuck on. Thank you so much!